# Error in trying to open web page with nodejs express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to develop a web page with nodejs express and mongodb. I have followed and analyzed the code from [this GitHub page](https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/nodejs-basics-tutorial/tree/master/06-handlebars) and I'm getting an error while trying to open the web page.

When uncommenting the below code part in `app.js` and commenting the rest portion of the code in the `app.js` file (uncommented code part):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/'}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

The following output is obtained:

```
Cannot GET /
```

When uncommenting all the statements in the `app.js` and executing to open the web page, the following output is obtained:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "C:\Users\web\first-1\views"
    at EventEmitter.render (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:966:7)
    at C:\Users\web\first-1\app.js:53:7
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at IncomingMessage.next (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at done (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:961:25)
    at EventEmitter.render (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:582:14)
```

Kindly help me out of this.

Comment: Check your views folder. Did you find the error.hbs file in it?

Comment: @sailesh error.hbs file is present in layouts directory under views directory

Comment: It should be in views directory.

Comment: @sailesh Thanks for your reply....layouts directory is present under views directory... Let me check with it...

Comment: error.hbs should be in views directory. Not in Layouts directory. It should be here views/error.hbs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

You have specified views directory for your app views. res.render looks for the files in the views directory, not in the sub directories of views. Copy your error.hbs from views/layouts to views/ and try.

Comment: thanks for your reply & answer... now the webpage is able to open